# ToolStripManager not restoring Location of Toolstrips

Tags: c#, winforms, toolstrip

ToolStripManager does not restore my Toolstrips to the previous locations as expected. I created a very simple app to demonstrate. I contains 4 movable Toolstrips in a ToolStrip Container. I move the toolstrips to order them as 4-3-2-1 from top to bottom (Figure A). Then close the app. When I reopen it they are ordered as in Figure B.

Here is the simple code. I have verified that the Key used in the LoadSettings and SaveSettings method calls is the same string.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ZT2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        string keyName = "abc";
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            keyName = Application.ProductName + this.Name + "xyz";
            ToolStripManager.LoadSettings(this, keyName);
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            ToolStripManager.SaveSettings(this, keyName);
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Figure A Before closing form]

## [image: Figure B Reopened form]

Visual Studio 2010 - C#
.Net 4 Client Profile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry was to quick...

You will have to save it somewhere in the configuration file or some other location and check those values every time it is shown.

Check this codesnippet out

[CODESNIPPET](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Forums/Thread/77600/)

Comment: Thanks for that code link. The ToolStripManager.SaveSettings method does save the ToolStrip Location info in the app User.Config xml file. So I suppose I could read it from there in my Form Load event method. I was really hoping that ToolStripManager would handle restoring Location. It already handles ToolStrip Visibility and ToolStripContainer Panel (Top , Bottom, Left, Right).

Comment: Exactly ;) I hope you find a solution that works! If you did mark as any of the answers or post your own answer and mark it.

Comment: Carl, Ok thanks. I've accepted you answer as a work around. I really wish Microsoft would attend to the Toolstrip Location restore. This has been ignored since .Net 2.0.

Comment: Codesnippet link is no longer working, Do anyone know what what the fix for this is?

Comment: Dead Link. Nill points for providing no code, just a link.

Answer (score 1):

Save setting on Form Closing by :

```
ToolStripManager.SaveSettings(this);
```

Load the setting in Form Load by :

```
ToolStripManager.LoadSettings(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

one problem with ToolStripContainer is that you cannot just set the location of a containing ToolStrip, as the container always checks the other ToolStrips in the container.

It's working fine if you do not place the ToolStrips in the container at design time. 
You just need a function to initialize them once.

Another possibility is to set the parent property of each Toolstrip to null before you call the ToolStripManager.LoadSettings function

Comment: Related to setting the location of ToolStrips manually; I've found you can set the locations without the ToolStripContainer repositioning them on you if you first make the containing ToolStripPanel invisible.

Comment: "set the parent property of each Toolstrip to null" didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone else ends up in ToolStripManager hell, here's my solution. Basically, it circumnavigates using ToolStripContainer and ToolStripManager entirely and persists the ToolStrip states (location and visibility) via a user setting and a custom control that inherits ToolStripPanel (placeable via VS Designer). This also persists multiple ToolStripPanels where ToolStrips are dragged between panels. Note: it doesn't do all the other features of ToolStripManager such as persisting the order of ToolStrip controls.

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Persists ToolStips via User Setting: ToolStripPanelItemLocations (you will need to create this)
/// Settings delimiter convention:
/// ToolStripPanelName|ToolStripName:LocationX,LocationY-Visible;ToolStripName:LocationX,LocationY-Visible
/// </summary>
[DesignerCategory("Code")]
[Browsable(true)]
public class ToolStripPanel : System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripPanel
{
    public override Color BackColor { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Auto Arrange"), Description("Left justifies all toolstrips")]
    public bool AutoArrange { get; set; } = false;


    private Form parentForm;

    protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (DesignMode) return; // skips persistence if code being executed through VS Designer view
        // Load Toolstrips
        LoadToolstripParameters();
        AddParentFormClosingEventHandler();
        base.OnHandleCreated(e);
    }
    protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        // overrides default background draw which has some odd behaivours (e.g. lightening the set bg color)
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(BackColor), e.ClipRectangle);
    }
    private void AddParentFormClosingEventHandler()
    {
        // found this to best approach - OnHandleDestroyed caused all toolstrips to show as invisible and Dispose was unreliable depending on context
        parentForm = this.FindForm();
        parentForm.FormClosing += ParentForm_FormClosing;
    }
    private void ParentForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        parentForm.FormClosing -= ParentForm_FormClosing;
        SaveToolStripParameters();
    } 

    private void LoadToolstripParameters()
    {
        // Grab existing persisted settings and asign to temp store
        StringCollection toolStripPanelItems = Properties.Settings.Default.ToolStripPanelItemLocations;

        // Initiate delimited string
        string delimitedString = String.Empty;

        // Find any existing enrty for this ToolStripPanel  
        for (int i = toolStripPanelItems.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (toolStripPanelItems[i].StartsWith($"{this.Name}|"))
            {
                delimitedString = toolStripPanelItems[i];
                break;
            }
        }

        // Test if entry exists
        if (delimitedString != String.Empty)
        {
            // remove the ToolStripPanel.Name text
            string allTsParameters = delimitedString.Replace($"{this.Name}|", String.Empty);

            // this pass removes the ToolStrip from the Panel and then re-adds them in reverse order at 0,0
            // the strips are shifted right when a new one is added to the left 
            foreach (string individTsParameters in allTsParameters.Split(';'))
            {
                if (individTsParameters == "") continue;
                // do the magic
                string[] toolstripNameSplit = individTsParameters.Split(':');

                Control toolstripControl = this.FindForm().Controls.Find(toolstripNameSplit[0], true).FirstOrDefault();

                if (toolstripControl == null) continue; // controls for toolstrip names changed in designer (mismatch between persisted Name and new Name)

                // first, de-parent 
                toolstripControl.Parent = null;

                string[] toolStripSizeSplit = toolstripNameSplit[1].Split('-');
                toolstripControl.Visible = true;
                toolstripControl.Location = new Point(0, 0);
                this.Controls.Add(toolstripControl);
            }

            // now strips are added, this changes the position of each toolstrip on the panel
            foreach (string individTsParameters in allTsParameters.Split(';'))
            {
                if (individTsParameters == "") continue;
                // do the magic
                string[] toolstripNameSplit = individTsParameters.Split(':');

                Control toolstripControl = this.FindForm().Controls.Find(toolstripNameSplit[0], true).FirstOrDefault();

                if (toolstripControl == null) continue; // controls for toolstrip names changed in designer (mismatch between persisted Name and new Name)


                string[] toolStripSizeSplit = toolstripNameSplit[1].Split('-');

                if (!AutoArrange) // only repositions toolstrips if autoarrange set to false
                {
                    toolstripControl.Location = new Point(Convert.ToInt16(toolStripSizeSplit[0].Split(',')[0])
                                                        , Convert.ToInt16(toolStripSizeSplit[0].Split(',')[1]));
                }

                toolstripControl.Visible = Convert.ToBoolean(toolStripSizeSplit[1]);
            }
        }
    }

    private void SaveToolStripParameters()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Saving Toolstrips");

        // Grab existing persisted settings and asign to tmep store
        StringCollection toolStripPanelItems = Properties.Settings.Default.ToolStripPanelItemLocations;

        // Initiate the stringbuilder used in the persistence process
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        // Add the ToolStripPanel.Name to the stringbuilder
        sb.Append($"{this.Name}|");

        // Search existing settings for this ToolStripPanel and remove line if present (add it back later)
        for (int i = toolStripPanelItems.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (toolStripPanelItems[i].StartsWith(sb.ToString())) toolStripPanelItems.RemoveAt(i);
        }

        List<Control> controls = new List<Control>();
        foreach (Control control in this.Controls) controls.Add(control);

        controls = controls.OrderByDescending(x => x.Location.X).ToList();

        // All controls need to be visible before saving locaiotn. Therefore do a pass getting visibilites
        Dictionary<string, bool> controlVisibilities = new Dictionary<string, bool>();
        foreach (Control control in controls)
        {
            controlVisibilities.Add(control.Name, control.Visible);
            control.Visible = true;
        }

        // Now add the delimited paramters for each ToolStrip in this ToolStripPanel
        foreach (Control control in controls)
            sb.Append($"{control.Name}:{control.Location.X},{control.Location.Y}-{controlVisibilities[control.Name]};");

        // Add the new details to the temp store and then update the Setting.
        toolStripPanelItems.Add(sb.ToString());
        Properties.Settings.Default.ToolStripPanelItemLocations = toolStripPanelItems;
        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    }
}
```

It probably needs some refactoring, but you're a long time dead, right?